# Laravel sanctum set expiration date

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

I am trying to add an expiration date when a token is made, but it does not work.

I don't know if I have to do more than that I have already

In my `sanctum.php` I have set the exparation to:

```
'expiration' => 525600,
```

This is my function where a token is created:

```
public function login(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|max:255'
        ]);

        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
        if (!$user || !Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)){
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'De ingevulde gegevens zijn fout'
            ]);
        }

        $token = $user->createToken($request->email);

        return response()->json([
            'response' => $token->plainTextToken
        ], 200);

    }
```

I've already tried to run: `php artisan config:clear`. And that did not work as well.

In my database the `expires_at` in the `personal_access_tokens` table stays null and I don't knwo why

Comment: `public function createToken(string $name, array $abilities = ['*'], DateTimeInterface $expiresAt = null)` ... another option for setting expiration

Comment: @lagbox do you mean that I have to create a standalone functionto make a token?

Comment: no, that is the signature of `createToken`, the 3rd argument is `$expiresAt`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by downloading the logs from my Beanstalk environment, I noticed it skipped the class because of a PSR-4 error, I simply renamed the file to comply with [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) standards. This should help. [eb logs screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci8JT.png)